# multiples ng-repeat for populate table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to populate the same table with values from different scope variables. The A and B will always have the same lenght.

```js
$scope.a = [1,2,3]
$scope.b = [4,5,6]
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="itemA in a, itemB in b"> <!-- How should be this ng-repeat?-->
      <td>{{itemA}}</td>
      <td>{{itemB}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The result should be a table like:

**A - B**

1 - 4

2 - 5

3 - 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that the two array will always have the same length:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="itemA in a track by $index"> 
      <td>{{itemA}}</td> <!--Could also be a[$index] -->
      <td>{{b[$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All it does is tracks the array by and index, and uses that index to get the necessary element in B.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the two arrays one and access the properties like so:

```
$scope.items = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 4    
}, {
    a: 2,
    b: 5    
}, {
    a: 3,
    b: 6    
}]

<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>{{item.a}}</td>
  <td>{{item.b}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) adds a few special values to the inner scope, including `$index`, which you could use to reference the corresponding value from `b`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="itemA in a">
  <td>{{ itemA }}</td>
  <td>{{ b[$index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Outside of the template, you could zip the arrays together with something like [lodash's `_.zip` function](https://lodash.com/docs#zip):

```
$scope.combinedArray = _.zip(a, b); // [[ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ]]
```